# Select every nth column in R from position x

Tags: r, seq

Imagine data is

```
v1<-c(1,2,3)
v2<-c(3,1,2)
v3<-c(5,4,3)
v4<-c(2,3,2)
v5<-c(6,2,1)
v6<-c(1,1,2)
v7<-c(2,2,1)
mydata<-data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
```

I would like every other column from position v3.

```
  v3 v5 v7
1  5  6  2
2  4  2  2
3  3  1  1
```

I am not sure how to use seq() from a certain position instead of the starting from the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match` with `seq` - `match` returns the position index of the column name that matches the 'v3', then use `seq` with `by` as 2 and `to` as the index of last column (`ncol`)

```
mydata[seq(match('v3', names(mydata)), ncol(mydata), by = 2)]
```

-output

```
  v3 v5 v7
1  5  6  2
2  4  2  2
3  3  1  1
```

---

Or in `dplyr` with `num_range`

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
   select(num_range(prefix = "v", range = seq(3, last_col(), by = 2)))
```

-output

```
  v3 v5 v7
1  5  6  2
2  4  2  2
3  3  1  1
```